# Using Bluetooth Dongle on Arduino

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I need to communicate my arduino by bluetooth but I'm living in a small town recently so I can't buy a bluetooth shield for my arduino.

Here is my question: Can I use a usb bluetooth dongle on my Arduino **without a shield?**
PS: There is no need to re-use that bluetooth dongle with usb again.

Answer (score 5):

You'll most likely need a USB host shield ([like this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947)) for the Arduino to be able to communicate with the dongle, so that doesn't help. You may (this is a long shot) be able to crack open the dongle, look up some datasheets, and possibly find a serial interface inside that you could connect to Arduino... but like I said, it's a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your Arduino is based on a AT90USBXX7, no. Bluetooth dongles are highly integrated and have no accessible interfaces other than USB.